# I want to reverse an array but dont know why this error comes?

Tags: java, arrays, function

i dont kow ehy my programs dont run.
i am trying to reverse my array through user defined function.
i can give an input but cannot find out the answer.

```
import java.util.*;
public class reverseanarray{
public static int reversea(int array[]){
    int swap;
    int j=array.length;
    for(int i=0;i<array.length/2;i++){
        swap=array[i];
        array[i]=array[j];
        array[j]=swap;
        j--;
    }
    return j;
}      
public static void main(String args[]){
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   //System.out.println();
   //int a = sc.nextInt();
   System.out.println("please input the length");
   int y=sc.nextInt();//INPUT OF LENGTH OF ARRAY
   int arr[]=new int[y];
       //INPUT ARRAY
       for(int r=0;r<arr.length;r++){
           System.out.println("please input the "+r+" index value");
           arr[r]=sc.nextInt();
       }
       System.out.println(reversea(arr));
       for(int i=0;i<y;i++){
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
       }
      
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is giving you an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, as you are trying to address an array index which is beyond array limits. The reason for this is, that arrays are 0-indexed, so an array of length 10 has indexes 0-9. Your code does not take this into account when defining field `j`.

The only change you need to make is change that line:

```
int j = array.length;
```

into this one:

```
int j = array.length - 1;
```

You could also do some more refactoring and rewrite method as:

```
public static int[] reversea(int array[]) {
    int swap;
    for (int i = 0, j = array.length-1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        swap = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = swap;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Instead of returning useless value of `j` after reversing, the refactored method returns the array in reversed order.

PS: Please use CamelCase for your class names.

Comment: What's the point of declaring `j` - use `array.length-1` directly instead. However, you can use `j` variable more usefully: `for (int i = 0, j = array.length-1; i < j; i++, j--)`, then use `j` directly inside the loop instead of `j-i`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Good point, I integrated this into my response.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is in method "reverseArray(int[] array)"

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

public class ArrayReverse {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    System.out.println("original array :: " + array + " : " + Arrays.toString(array));
    reverseArray(array);
    System.out.println("reversed array :: " + array + " : " + Arrays.toString(array));
}

public static void reverseArray(int[] array) {
    // We will iterate on the half of the array length
    // If the array size is an even number (e.g.: {1 ,2 ,3 ,4} we will iterate on
    // the half of the array size (e.g.: 2 numbers)
    // If the array size is an odd number (e.g.: {1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5} we will iterate on
    // the half of the array size minus 1 (e.g.: 2 numbers)
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++) {
        // We add the value of the number at index i in array (let's say its value is x)
        // to the value of the number at index (length of array-i-1) of the array (let's
        // say value y)
        array[i] = array[i] + array[array.length - 1 - i];
        // Now the value of array[i] is x+y
        // We retrieve the value of the number at index (length of array-i-1) from the
        // number at index i in array
        array[array.length - 1 - i] = array[i] - array[array.length - 1 - i];
        // Now the value of array[length of array-i-1] is (x+y)-y=x
        // And finally, we retrieve the value of the number at index (length of
        // array-i-1) from number at index i in array
        array[i] = array[i] - array[array.length - 1 - i];
        // Now the value of array[i] is (x+y)-x=y
        // We have swapped x and y values in the array
    }
}
```

}

This can seem a bit complicated but this method only use addition and substraction, no complicated algorithm.
Furthermore, there is no variable instance created except variable "i" as a counter on array index.
And, finally, no new array is created. The reversed array is the original array instance simply reversed.

Comment: It would make for a better answer if a) you address the issues in OP's code; b) explain what your code does, and how that relates to OP's issues.

Comment: Hi Andy Turner! You're right, it needs some comments. They've been added. What do you mean by "OP's"?